# How to hook a C function on iOS without the function signature?

Tags: ios, c, hook

On iOS, if we want to hook a C function before the main function, we could create a framework embed in the project and then define the same function as the hooked function such as `getenv` and `printf`. However, when we don't know the signature of the hooked function, we will be not able to define the same function, then how do we hook this kind of functions such as `pthread_start`.

Comment: err, what is the point of tampering with a method when you don't know its signature? What exactly is the *underlying* problem you intend to solve by doing this?

Comment: OK，what I want to do is to count the number of threads in a real time. Therefore, I want to hook the pthread's functions, `start` and `exit`. Then I can handle the number of threads in a real time.

Comment: Of course, we can use a timer to count the numbers of threads every second as well. However, I think that is a time-consuming operation.

Comment: So, basically, you want to *instrument* certain "system calls" in order to get runtime "profile" data. Sounds reasonable ...

Comment: you can just wrap threads in your own class where you count  amount of threads